# что делает self.next?

Tags: python, ооп

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.next = None
        self.data = data
    def append(self, val):
        end = Node(val)
        n = self
        while (n.next):
            n = n.next
        n.next = end
```

оно создает указатель на какую-то переменную!?

Comment: Это поле объекта класса. Оно само по себе ничего не создает и не делает. В контексте связных списков в поле next может храниться ссылка на следующий узел списка.

Comment: "что делает" - представьте вот лежит коробка на столе лежит, и вы спрашиваете что она делает или что она создает. Ну, технически она конечно лежит. Коробка сама по себе ничего не делает и не создает. Может что-то хранить. Что конкретно - что в нее положат, то и будет хранить.

Comment: тут скорее вопрос был что делает метод .next, как объяснили next это поле и в нем хранится ссылка на слебущий узел списка , но в питоне вроде в отличии от С++ ссылок и указателей нет , и немного диссонанс вызвало это у меня.

Comment: Тут нет метода next, есть только поле. Указателей в Python действительно нет, но любая переменная фактически является ссылкой на какой-то объект.

Answer (score 2):

В данном примере на мой взгляд несколько нарушены принципы ООП. Класс "Узел" (Node) одновременно отвечает и за конкретный узел и за весь связный список, построенный на этих узлах. Согласно принципам `SOLID` так лучше не делать. Буква `S` в названии принципа означает "single responsibility". Класс должен отвечать только за что-то одно. За узел - так за узел. За список - так за список. А тут что получается, сначала создаётся один узел:

```
Node1:
data = value
next = None
```

Потом на узле вызывается `append`, тогда создаётся следующий узел и ставится после имеющегося:

```
Node1:         Node2:
data = value1  data = value2
next -> Node2  next = None
```

Добавим ещё один узел:

```
Node1:         Node2:         Node3
data = value1  data = value2  data = value3
next -> Node2  next -> Node3  next = None
```

В общем, поле `next` объекта `Node` указывает на следующий `Node` в цепочке, являющейся однонаправленным списком.

Таким образом класс `Node` берёт на себя и функции узла в цепочке и функции однонаправленного списка узлов. Ну то есть само указание на следующий узел тут нормально, по-другому это не сделать. Но искать, куда прицепить следующий узел, а для этого проходить по цепочке узлов, должен какой-то другой объект (например, `List`), более высокого уровня, на мой взгляд.

Хотя с точки зрения использования применённый подход, конечно, удобен - `append` можно вызывать от любого узла, он сам найдёт конец цепочки. Хотя это тоже не есть хорошо - нет единого объекта, отвечающего за список, каждый узел списка может добавить в цепочку другой узел, начав поиск с себя. С точки зрения ООП это как-то странно выглядит, должно быть всё-таки разделение ответственности, объекты одного уровня иерархии не должны лазить в свойства друг-друга и менять их. )

Answer (score 0):

В этом коде `self.next` - это атрибут экземпляра класса `Node`, который ссылается на следующий узел (экземпляр класса `Node`) в связанном списке.

В методе `append`, создается новый узел `end` с переданным значением `val`, затем переменной `n` присваивается ссылка на текущий экземпляр класса `Node`. Далее происходит проход по связанному списку, пока `n.next` не будет равно `None` (т.е. пока не будет достигнут конец списка). Затем новый узел `end` добавляется в конец списка путем установки ссылки на `end` в `n.next`. Таким образом, новый узел становится последним элементом в связанном списке.